# How is this gcc-generated strlen() mips loop not off-by-one?

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips, strlen, off-by-one

Here is the source code for a very basic `strlen()` implementation.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern uintptr_t lx_syscall3(uintptr_t a, uintptr_t b, uintptr_t c, uintptr_t nr);

static void lx_sys_exit(uintptr_t code)
{
  lx_syscall3(code, 0, 0, 4001);
  while (1);
}

static size_t lx_strlen(char const* s)
{
  size_t len = 0;

  while (*(s++)) {
    len++;
  }

  return len;
}

int main() {
  lx_sys_exit(lx_strlen("HELO"));
  while (1);
}
```

Compiled together with a `syscall.s` file not relevant to this question, the generated GCC code for `lx_strlen` is inlined into `main` (at `-Os`):

```
004004fc <main>:
  4004fc: 3c1c000b  lui gp,0xb
  400500: 279c8154  addiu gp,gp,-32428
  400504: 0399e021  addu gp,gp,t9
  400508: 8f828034  lw v0,-32716(gp)
  40050c: 27bdffe0  addiu sp,sp,-32
  400510: 24424a64  addiu v0,v0,19044
  400514: afbc0010  sw gp,16(sp)
  400518: afbf001c  sw ra,28(sp)
  40051c: 00402825  move a1,v0
  400520: 00452023  subu a0,v0,a1

  # strlen loop block follows
  400524: 24420001  addiu v0,v0,1
  400528: 8043ffff  lb v1,-1(v0)
  40052c: 5460fffd  bnezl v1,400524 <main+0x28>
  400530: 00452023  subu a0,v0,a1

  400534: 8f998118  lw t9,-32488(gp)
  400538: 24070fa1  li a3,4001
  40053c: 00003025  move a2,zero
  400540: 04110093  bal 400790 <lx_syscall3>
  400544: 00002825  move a1,zero
  400548: 1000ffff  b 400548 <main+0x4c>
  40054c: 00000000  nop
```

When run with `qemu-mipsel`, the code correctly outputs exit status `4`. So it seems to work OK, the problem is that I'm just not understanding *how* it can possibly work. Notice the offset `-1(v0)` at `400528`. So the loop is always checking the preceding byte from the address stored in `v0`. Thus by the time that's zero, subtracting out the original address should yield `5`, not `4`. Any idea how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is using the `bnezl` instruction which has a special handling of the delay slot instruction: it's only executed if the branch is taken. Hence, your code will always use the `$a0` from the previous iteration because the `subu a0,v0,a1` at `400530` is not executed for the final one that exits the loop. Note that at `400520` `$a0` is zeroed for the case of a zero length string.